# How to add bootstrap to a nodejs project

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I have already run

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and its located in the node_modules file, but I'm not seeing it link with my .html files. I know I can include the style sheets with the bootstrap url, but I'd rather set it up "right". Is there a certain file path I need to add to the index.html file, or something?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to reference both the JS and CSS files. You also need to reference **'bootstrap'** rather than 'boostrap'.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Oops! How would I reference the CSS files of bootstrap? Could you show me an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to add bootstrap to your node project you have to type *npm install --save bootstrap* and it will run a little time and after installation you will see a bootstrap library in *node_modules* folder.

After you can set up bootstrap to your project. To do it you have to edit *angular-cli.json* file.Go into it and open inverted commas inside the square bracket under styles and type as this *"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"* save it. Then start the server again by giving command *ng serve*. I hope you could be able to manage your issue.